# Change the height and width on a google map in React js

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

Hi guys i am working on a small presentation project. I need make a google map with the ability to auto search location. I found a code what does all that from a tutorial but i can't change the width and the height. I need it to be small, something like: height: 200px and width: 200px.

GoogleMap.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Map, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';
import PlacesAutocomplete, {
  geocodeByAddress,
  getLatLng,
} from 'react-places-autocomplete';

export class MapContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // for google map places autocomplete
      address: '',

      showingInfoWindow: false,
      activeMarker: {},
      selectedPlace: {},
  
      mapCenter: {
        lat: 49.2827291,
        lng: -123.1207375
      }
    };
  }

  handleChange = address => {
    this.setState({ address });
  };

  handleSelect = address => {
    this.setState({ address });
    geocodeByAddress(address)
      .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then(latLng => {
        console.log('Success', latLng);

        // update center state
        this.setState({ mapCenter: latLng });
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error', error));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id='googleMaps'>
        <PlacesAutocomplete
          value={this.state.address}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onSelect={this.handleSelect}
        >
          {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (
            <div>
              <input
                {...getInputProps({
                  placeholder: 'Search Places ...',
                  className: 'location-search-input',
                })}
              />
              <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container">
                {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
                {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                  const className = suggestion.active
                    ? 'suggestion-item--active'
                    : 'suggestion-item';
                  // inline style for demonstration purpose
                  const style = suggestion.active
                    ? { backgroundColor: '#fafafa', cursor: 'pointer' }
                    : { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', cursor: 'pointer' };
                  return (
                    <div
                      {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                        className,
                        style,
                      })}
                    >
                      <span>{suggestion.description}</span>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </PlacesAutocomplete>

        <Map 
          google={this.props.google}
          initialCenter={{
            lat: this.state.mapCenter.lat,
            lng: this.state.mapCenter.lng
          }}
          center={{
            lat: this.state.mapCenter.lat,
            lng: this.state.mapCenter.lng
          }}
        >
          <Marker 
            position={{
              lat: this.state.mapCenter.lat,
              lng: this.state.mapCenter.lng
            }} />
        </Map>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: ('_MY_API_KEY_')
})(MapContainer)
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import GoogleMap from './components/GoogleMap';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Google Maps App</h1>
      <GoogleMap />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have error in the console but I don't know if they are connected with this problem.

Here they are:

> Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code. See https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

> Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.

> If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at: https://reactjs.org/link/derived-state

> Please update the following components: Wrapper

> Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the Wrapper component.

> index.js:1 Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code. See https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

> Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.

> If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at: https://reactjs.org/link/derived-state

> Please update the following components: Wrapper

I saw that other people had this problem also but their solutions didn't help me. Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap the map container in a div and set it's height and width using css. I think that should work

Comment: Doesn't do anything. I even put !important just to be safe on the height and the width but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a small change in div created by the script. It should work

```
  return (
      <div id='googleMaps' style="width:200px; height:200px">
        <PlacesAutocomplete
```

Comment: This solution doesn't change the height and width and gives me the warning: "src\components\GoogleMap.js
  Line 45:28:  Style prop value must be an object  react/style-prop-object".

Comment: I also tried this because i think it is the proper syntax: style={{height:"100px", width:"100px"}}, but also doesn't work. Just no error or warning